Intermittent 503 response on Varnish
A HTTP request in our case first hits the Varnish server and then one of its two backends. The backends service is a flask+uwsgi application.
I have observed that during peak traffic hours, the varnish servers returns intermittent 503 response codes for some of the requests in very less numbers. While tracking such requests on varnish I have found the following on varnish:
FetchError     HTC status -1
BackendClose   32 reload_2024-09-18T174244.ml1
BerespStatus   503
BerespReason   Service Unavailable
BerespReason   Backend fetch failed

I have tried increasing the number of processes and threads for the backend application but this has no impact on 5xx numbers.
Another observation was, most of these 5xx requests have response time of less than 1 millisecond which means this aren't getting timed out in any case.
Can anyone provide some insights on the issue? Thanks in advance.

HTTP 503 is Service Unavailable. You should try using a retry strategy which, if you're using requests, is trivial

According to https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/1a79fde343ebd9f7210ea2489df6e9730940653f/include/tbl/htc.h#L41, the HTC status -1 error has the following description:
Unexpected end of input

This can imply that the backend disconnected before Varnish received the expected data.
Varnishlog for failed transactions
I'd like to see more detailed varnishlog output for these error cases.
You could run the following command to capture the fetch errors as they occur:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "FetchError"

You can also dump the full VSL memory buffer and look for earlier transactions that had a fetch error but running the following command:
sudo varnishlog -d -g request -q "FetchError"

I'd like to see the complete log for one individual transaction that fails in the way you're describing.
It would also be interesting if you could match the timestamp of that failure to any kind of web server or application error/debug log.
Health checking
Does your VCL backend have a health probe? If so, I'd like to see the output from the following command:
sudo varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health

If you don't have health probe, it would be good to define one. Here's a VCL snippet that illustrates how to do this:

probe health {
    .url = "/check";
    .interval = 5s;
    .window = 5;
    .threshold = 3;
    .initial = 2; 
}

backend one {
 .host = "server1.example.com";
 .port = "80";
 .probe = health;
}

backend two {
 .host = "server1.example.com";
 .port = "80";
 .probe = health;
}

More information on backend health probes can be found on https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vcl-probe.html.
Next steps
Backend health checks will paint a realtime picture of the current backend health, which is useful information. However, the combination of real log transactions and health probes is ideal.
If you can match any of these backends issues to errors in your application log, we may find a root cause.
